# Strange Java compiler warning: incorrect "potential null access warning"

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, compiler-warnings

(JDK 1.6.0_23, Eclipse 3.7.0 with "Potential null pointer access" warning level at "Warning") Consider the following example code:

```
Object obj = null;
for (;;) {
    obj = getObject();
    if (obj != null) break;
    Thread.sleep(25);
}
obj.toString();
```

I'm getting the following warning on the last line: `Potential null pointer access: The variable obj may be null at this location`. Is there any real way for `obj` to actually be `null` or why the compiler thinks so?

Comment: I don't get a warning? Which line is it?

Comment: does it give the same warning when you remove `.toString()`?

Comment: Which compiler?  (JDK 1.6.0_23 `javac` I guess.)  What compiler switches?

Comment: @JohnnyCageWins no, it doesnt; Stephen: Eclipse 3.7.0 with no changes, edited a post.

Comment: This is also discussed [here](http://pastebin.com/68h3YxVm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is seeing this as a potential that the object will not be initialized. It is not really able to see that the loop breaking condition is that the object is not null or it will just run forever or until it is no longer null. I only get the warning on the JDK you mentioned. Using a more updated version this warning does not appear.

Answer (score 8):

I'd say the compiler sees this as:

```
Object obj = null;
[Too dumb to interpret this loop]
obj.toString();
```

So obj.toString() could be null if you cannot interpret what the loop does.

For example you can trick the compiler by replacing:

```
void x(int x){
    return;  
    x++;  //error unreachable code
}
```

with

```
void x(int x){
    if(true) return;
    x++;  //compiles
}
```

Comment: Well, compiler frequently understands much more complicated loops, and I dont get, why cant it analyze this one.

Comment: Yes, last one compiles, but you still get a proper `Dead Code` warning.

Comment: Interesting side node: The fact that the compiler is too dumb to analyze the `if (true)` is *specified in the JLS*. It's a requirement. Try replacing it with `while (true)` (which is handled differently in the JLS).

Comment: @Frozen Spider - not really a relevant question.  The fact is that it can't.  But if you really want to know, look at the source code ... and check to see if there are bug reports in the Bugs database for this oddity.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer - not strictly true.  The compiler is allowed to analyse this (and optimize away the dead code) but it is not allowed to treat it as an "unreachable code" **error**.  In fact, this case is rather different to the OP's case.

Comment: @Frozen Spider - correction to my above: since this the an Eclipse compiler artifact check the Eclipse issues tracker.

Comment: @Stephen C: I should have made that more clear: I was talking only about the errors specified by the JLS: the compiler *most not* treat the `return;` as unreachable code as defined in the JLS. Is *may* be smart enough and post a warning, but the required dead code detection specified in the JLS does *not* consider this to be dead code.

Comment: @JoachimSauer AFAIK this requirement is in place to help avoid issues with this kind of code: `private boolean DEV = true; [...] if(DEV) log(something);`

Answer (score 4):

It seems that compiler cannot analyze the code very well. It actually cannot "run" it and understand that your `if` statement prevents null access. I played a little bit with the code and found the following equivalent version that does not produce warning:

```
    Object obj = null;
    do {
        obj = getObject();
        if (obj == null) {
            Thread.sleep(25);
        }
    } while (obj == null);
    obj.toString();
```

Yes, I know that this version performs 2 null checks on each loop iteration instead of one. So, it is up to you to change your code, add `@SuppressWarning` to your code or to remove `Thread.sleep(25)`

Answer (score 3):

This is an improved version of AlexR's code which I think is a nice solution to the problem while also improving readability of the code. My version features a second `obj = getObject();` line, but doesn't need the second check, so it should be more performant overall.

```
Object obj = null;
obj = getObject();
while (obj == null) {
    Thread.sleep(25);
    obj = getObject();
}
obj.toString();
```

Comment: you are right that your version performs only on null check (+1). But I think that both my `if()` into the loop and your call to `getObject()` before the loop just make code less readable. Probably `@SuppressWarning` on original code is better solution in this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old thread, but how about this? I find it more readable than the versions of Koraktor and AlexR.

```
Object obj = null;
for (obj=getObject(); obj==null; obj=getObject()) {
  Thread.sleep(25);
}
obj.toString();
```

But in my code, I usually have enabled "Include 'assert' in null analysis" in eclipse compiler settings and add an assert. So I don't have to change control flow and at the same time avoid the warning:

```
Object obj = null;    
while (true) {
    obj = getObject();
    if (obj != null) break;
    Thread.sleep(25);
}
assert obj!=null;
obj.toString();
```