# How do I avoid "potential null pointer access" when using Preconditions.checkNotNull()?

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, guava

Eclipse gives me the warning "Potential null pointer access: The variable ann may be null at this location":

```
SomeAnnotation ann = type.getAnnotation( SomeAnnotation.class );
Preconditions.checkNotNull( ann, "Missing annotation on %s", type );

for( String value : ann.value() ) { // <-- warning happens here
}
```

I'm using Eclipse 3.7 and [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). Is there a way to get rid of this warning?

I could use `SuppressWarnings("null")` but I would have to attach it to the method which I feel would be a bad idea.

Comment: May this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772129/strange-java-compiler-warning-incorrect-potential-null-access-warning

Comment: I tried `SomeAnnotation.value()` which returns `String[]`, and no null warning. What's your `SomeAnnotation` looks like?

Comment: It doesn't matter; the problem is that `ann` could be null.

Comment: Chances are: it's the policy on the manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse e4 has much better support for null checks and resource tracking in the compiler.

Another solution is writing your own version of `checkNotNull` like so:

```
@Nonnull
public static <T> T checkNotNull(@Nullable T reference) {
  if (reference == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException();
  }
  return reference;   
}
```

Now you can use this approach:

```
SomeAnnotation ann = Preconditions.checkNotNull( type.getAnnotation( SomeAnnotation.class ) );
```

(I've omitted the version of `checkNotNull()` which take error messages; they work in the same way).

I'm wondering why Guava doesn't do that since they already use these annotation elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You could stop using Eclipse.

Hey, it's a solution. It may not be the one you want, but it solves the problem and isn't really a bad solution.

More seriously, you could:

- adjust compiler warning settings,
- use `SuppressWarnings` at method or class level,
- use a more modern compiler (apparently later versions do not trigger this for simple cases),
- rewrite your code to work and assign the return value of `checkNotNull` to `ann`.

Comment: I agree that it's a solution but I would prefer one which just changed the code instead of changing the way 20 people are used to work :-)

Comment: It's funny how people downvote this just because they don't like the first sentence, and discard the valid suggestions following it. And it's still a solution too.